# How to display a record field from dbgrid to an editbox

Tags: delphi, ms-access-2010, delphi-7

I have built an access database and connected it with an `ADOquery` and `Datasource`.I have built a table named `BagCost` which has field names `bag size` and `cost`. I have attached a `DBgrid` into a form and linked it with the "Bagcost" table. The `Dbgrid` has the following fields:

[image]

How can I display the four costs from the dbgrid column to different `editboxes` at runtime?

Comment: Are you asking about how to create a `TEdit` component at runtime for each record in your dataset? What is the count of the records in your dataset - always four? Thanks.

Comment: I have already created the four `editboxes`  in the form. I only need to display the costs to these `editboxes`. The count of records will not change. However, if the records change, then I will have to create `Tedit` component at runtime.

Comment: I've added the `delphi` tag, because this question is not only about Delphi 7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Explanations:**

I hope I understand you correctly. What you need to do is to read data from each of your four records. Use `First` and `Next` methods to change the active record, `Eof` method to test if the active record is the last record in a dataset. Optionally (for large number of records), use `DisableControls` and `EnableControls` methods to prevent data-aware controls from updating every time the active record changes.

**Example:**

Next is a basic example, that uses `AfterOpen` event to read field values from each record of your query.

```
procedure TfrmMain.qryAfterOpen(DataSet: TDataSet);
begin
   DataSet.DisableControls;
   try
      DataSet.First;
      if not DataSet.Eof then Edit1.Text := DataSet.FieldByName('cost').AsString else Edit1.Text := 'Record not found';
      DataSet.Next;
      if not DataSet.Eof then Edit2.Text := DataSet.FieldByName('cost').AsString else Edit2.Text := 'Record not found';
      DataSet.Next;
      if not DataSet.Eof then Edit3.Text := DataSet.FieldByName('cost').AsString else Edit3.Text := 'Record not found';
      DataSet.Next;
      if not DataSet.Eof then Edit4.Text := DataSet.FieldByName('cost').AsString else Edit4.Text := 'Record not found';
      DataSet.First;
   finally
      DataSet.EnableControls;
   end{try};
end;
```

Comment: Thanks for this code Zhorov. It works perfectly after putting the right names of the `dataset` according to my application. I did not know how to implement the `first`, `next` and `eof` methods to read records in a sequence. I only use queries to retrieve a single record.